# FOSElasticaBundle user indexes

Tags: symfony, elasticsearch, foselasticabundle

I'm using symfony and elasticsearch with FOSElasticaBundle.

I've got 2 entities:  User, and UserItems.

Is there a way to create a own index for each user automatically? so each logged in user can only search his own index (UserItems).

Thanks in advance!